# Align the radio buttons on the center whatever the text length

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 3 radio buttons with 3 labels next to them, 2 of them have the same characters length so they are aligned beneath each other, But the one in the middle is longer that them, So it's not aligned with the other 2.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xquj471a/18/).

The code:

```css
.wrapper{
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle
}

.radio-wrapper{
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.radio{
    position: relative;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block !important;
    zoom: 1;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.radio span{
    zoom: 1;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.radio input[type=radio]{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -20px
}

.radio input{
  border: none;
  background: none;
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  text-align: center;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
}

input[type=radio] {
    margin: 4px 0 0;
    line-height: normal;
}

label{
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  vertical-align: sub;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="center-block wrapper">
    <div class="radio-wrapper">
      <div class="radio" id="uniform-trans-1">
        <span>
          <input type="radio" name="transaction" id="trans-1" value="0">
        </span>
      </div> <!-- .radio -->
      <label for="trans-1">Faster than I expected?</label>
    </div> <!-- .radio-wrapper -->
    <div class="radio-wrapper">
      <div class="radio" id="uniform-trans-2">
        <span>
          <input type="radio" name="transaction" id="trans-2" value="1">
        </span>
      </div> <!-- .radio -->
      <label for="trans-2">About the time I expected?</label>
    </div> <!-- .radio-wrapper -->
    <div class="radio-wrapper">  
      <div class="radio" id="uniform-trans-3">
        <span>
          <input type="radio" name="transaction" id="trans-3" value="2">
        </span>
      </div> <!-- .radio -->
      <label for="trans-3">Longer than I expected?</label>
    </div> <!-- .radio-wrapper -->
  </div> <!-- .wrapper -->
</div> <!-- .container -->
```

How to align the 3 inputs beneath each other, So that all the 3 inputs would be aligned beneath each other whatever the label text length next to them?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.radio-wrapper{
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  margin-left: 45%;
}

.radio{
    position: relative;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block !important;
    zoom: 1;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.radio span{
    zoom: 1;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.radio input[type=radio]{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -20px
}
```

Try this CSS code for it. Also delete the css tag named ".wrapper".

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using bootstrap 3.3.7. Therefore, I edited your html to be compliant. I then removed unnecessary css for my demonstration and added  `display: table !important` to override the default bootstrap behavior which allows usto collapse the extra space around and center the container.

http://jsfiddle.net/xquj471a/75/

CSS:

```
.center-block{display: table !important;}
```

Html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="center-block">
    <div class="radio">
      <label for="trans-1">
        <input type="radio" name="transaction" id="trans-1" value="0">
        Faster than I expected?
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label for="trans-2">
        <input type="radio" name="transaction" id="trans-2" value="1">
        About the time I expected?
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label for="trans-3">
        <input type="radio" name="transaction" id="trans-3" value="2">
        About the time I expected?
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I check out your code and i found you did not used the bootstrap classes that you really need. According to below code, "row" and "col-md-*" classes can help you: (replace HTML code and remove extra classes that you wrote)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="radio col-md-1" id="uniform-trans-1">
    <span>
      <input type="radio" name="transaction" id="trans-1" value="0">
    </span>
  </div> <!-- .radio -->
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label for="trans-1">Faster than I expected?</label>
  </div>
</div> <!-- .radio-wrapper -->

<div class="row">
  <div class="radio col-md-1" id="uniform-trans-2">
    <span>
      <input type="radio" name="transaction" id="trans-2" value="1">
    </span>
  </div> <!-- .radio -->
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label for="trans-2">About the time I expected?</label>
  </div>
</div> <!-- .radio-wrapper -->

<div class="row">
  <div class="radio col-md-1" id="uniform-trans-3">
    <span>
      <input type="radio" name="transaction" id="trans-3" value="2">
    </span>
  </div> <!-- .radio -->
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label for="trans-3">Longer than I expected?</label>
  </div>
</div> <!-- .radio-wrapper -->
```

more explanation about mentioned classes:

1. "row":
   "row" class uses to understand browser that we want divide contents using "col-md-*" classes
2. "col-md-*":
   when we use "row", sum of numbers that are at end of "col-md-*"(s) should not be more than 12. Actually each "row" has 12 parts that we can attribute them to different contents(div tags) via "col-md-*" classes.

more information in [bootstrap grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) ...

good luck!

Comment: Hi parsa, welcome to SO. Please consider explaining what those CSS classes do, since this code snippet does not help the questioner learn anything about how that solution works. Thanks for contributing!